# How to delete the rows with pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame as below. I want to delete rows which has RegionName containing [edit]. I appreciate any help.

```
    State   RegionName1
0   Alabama Alabama[edit]
1   Alabama Auburn
2   Alabama Florence
3   Alabama Jacksonville
4   Alabama Livingston
9   Alaska  Alaska[edit]
10  Alaska  Fairbanks
11  Arizona Arizona[edit]
12  Arizona Flagstaff
13  Arizona Tempe
15  Arkansas    Arkansas[edit]
16  Arkansas    Arkadelphia
18  Arkansas    Fayetteville
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.str.endswith()` method:

```
In [165]: df = df.loc[~df.RegionName1.str.endswith('[edit]')]

In [166]: df
Out[166]:
       State   RegionName1
1    Alabama        Auburn
2    Alabama      Florence
3    Alabama  Jacksonville
4    Alabama    Livingston
6     Alaska     Fairbanks
8    Arizona     Flagstaff
9    Arizona         Tempe
11  Arkansas   Arkadelphia
12  Arkansas  Fayetteville
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete, you just need to select the ones that don't have 'edit' in them:

```
df = df[~df.RegionName1.str.contains('edit')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to get an appropriate filter.

```
df = df[~df.RegionName1.str.contains('[edit]')]
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df
     RegionName1     State
0  Alabama[edit]   Alabama
1        Alabama   Alabama
2   Alaska[edit]    Alaska
3       Arkansas  Arkansas

>>> df = df[~df.RegionName1.str.contains('[edit]')]

>>> df
  RegionName1     State
1     Alabama   Alabama
3    Arkansas  Arkansas
```